# Beautify in VS Code: Is there a way to use single-line formatting for styles with one property, but multi-line for styles with multiple properties?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, js-beautify

I use Beautify obsessively to keep my CSS nice and clean.

However, I wish I could have it use single-line formatting for single-property styles, and multi-line formatting for multi-property styles.

**One Property:**

❌ What it gives me:

```
#slidebox {
        background-color: #000000;
    }
```

✅ What I want:

```
#slidebox {background-color: #000000;}
```

**Multiple Properties:**

✅ What it gives me AND what I want:

```
#slidebox {
        background-color: #000000;
        width: 360px;
        height: 475px;
        left: 568px;
    }
```

Is it possible to tweak a setting somewhere to do this? I've searched quite a bit and haven't found anything.

Thanks for your help!